# Why Dollar ($) Sign is not accepting in password for ldap user?

Tags: ssh, authentication, ldap, raspberry-pi, sshpass

Password is "**abc$123**" for ldap user it was successfully set using ldappasswd but when login with this password it's give error of **Invalid Credential**.
But using `sshpass -p ssh abc$123 user@ip_add` it was successfully login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ is a valid character and is usually accepted by LDAP servers in passwords.
But it is a special character in shell, and you should escape or quote the string to avoid the shell to transform the password string.

Comment: i tried with escape and  quote it was failed . I got **0x31** errno. and "**abc123$**" it was successfully login.but when i put "**$**" middle of password it was failed.

Comment: Then there is a chance that your server is using crypt and truncates passwords at the $ sign.

Comment: "$" sign might be use as delimiter in ldap? like name$surname$country ?

Comment: $ is used as a delimited in LDAP only for attributes that have a multi-line syntax (such as postalAddress).